# Why ISO 8601 date format 'yyyy-mm-dd' string literal works even when dateformat setting for user's login is set to 'mdy'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, datetime

I ran below query:

```
dbcc useroptions
```

It tells that my `dateformat` setting is `mdy`.

Then I run below query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) which runs successfully:

```
declare @mydate as datetime

set @mydate = '07-29-2017' -- 'mdy' formatted date string corresponding to 29 August, 2017

select @mydate
```

Now, I ran below query:

```
declare @mydate as datetime

set @mydate = '29-07-2017' --here the format is dmy so SQL Server fails to parse it

select @mydate
```

The above query results in below error:

> Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 5 The conversion of a varchar data
>   type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

The error is fairly acceptable to me as there is a mismatch in the date format. But, when I run below query it succeeds:

```
declare @mydate as datetime

set @mydate = '2017-07-29' -- this ymd format is also conflicting with mdy setting but it succeeds

select @mydate
```

So, I want to understand that SQL Server's capability to parse any string date time is dependent upon this `dateformat` setting in `useroptions` at all or not? If yes then why the ISO 8601 date format `yyyy-MM-dd` string date is getting successfully parsed? If no, then what is the driving setting/reason for this successful parsing?

Comment: [ISO 8601](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190977(v=sql.90).aspx) `The advantage in using the ISO 8601 format is that it is an international standard` and `this format is not affected by the SET DATEFORMAT or SET LANGUAGE settings`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got the citation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#UsingOperatorswithDateandTimeDataTypes) which clears the air on my issue.

In general the date time format for string literals are indeed controlled by the date format and language settings of the user login for the SQL session:

> String literal formats affect the presentation of data in applications
>   to users but not the underlying integer storage format in SQL Server.
>   However, SQL Server might interpret a date value in a string literal
>   format, input by an application or user for storage or to a date
>   function, as different dates. The interpretation depends on the
>   combination of string literal format, data type, and runtime SET
>   DATEFORMAT, SET LANGUAGE and default language option settings.

But ISO 8601 is independent of user's default language setting:

> Some string literal formats are not affected by these settings.
>   Consider using a format that does not depend on these settings, unless
>   you know the settings are correct for the format. The ISO 8601 format
>   does not depend on these settings and is an international standard.
>   Transact-SQL that uses string literal formats, dependent on system
>   settings, is less portable.

There is one more special case of date string literals which is independent of dateformat setting of SQL session for the user login - `string literals without delimiters`. Such dates doesn't belong to any local or international format but are always assumed to be in `ymd` format. Quoting from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.105).aspx#UnseparatedStringFormat) link:

> You can specify date data as an unseparated string. The date data can
>   be specified by using four, six, or eight digits, an empty string, or
>   a time value without a date value. The SET DATEFORMAT session setting
>   does not apply to all-numeric date entries, such as numeric entries
>   without separators. The six-digit or eight-digit strings are always
>   interpreted as ymd. The month and day must always be two digits.

Comment: . . That is really good.  My only issue is that ISO 8601 allows hyphens in the representation, but SQL Server does not always do so.  (Just look at the example at https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html.)

Comment: Your observation is correct but any date without delimiters doesn't belong to ISO 8601 format at all as per SQL Server also. They are again treated specially and differently. They are hardcodedly assumed to be in `ymd` format. I've quoted the citation for that as well in my post now. Treatment is same but it is not assumed to be in ISO 8601 format.

Answer (score 2):

This will always work in SQL Server:

```
set @mydate = '20170729'
```

regardless of internationalization settings (as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql#supported-string-literal-formats-for-datetime)).  This does not exactly answer your question, but it points out that `dateformat` is not all encompassing.

I suspect that the version with hyphens is accepted with out of altruism (SQL Server identifies the year being first) or because it is very similar to the ODBC format.

Comment: Thanks for your response Gordon. I was never worried about hyphens. I knew that SQL Server is able to parse date time without delimiters as well. I was finally able to get an exact citation in MSDN documentation corresponding to the issue I was facing. I've added an answer for the same. +1.